# When running a function in R using mapply, the output I observe is not why I expected

Tags: r, function, apply, mapply

I want to run a function and extract outputs for objects within the function. The output I am expecting is a dataframe with 5 rows and 5 columns. Instead, I obtain a 1000 rows with 5 columns.

Here is the code with reproducible example:

```
input.rows3 <- data.frame(pd=c(38, 50, 50, 86, 38),
                          Cl=c(15, 40, 30, 81, 15),
                          va=c(150, 145, 160, 141, 150),
                          co=c(3.0, 4.5, 4.0, 4.8, 1.5))

P <- c(seq(0,184,length.out=1000))

deriv.model <- function(a,b,c,x){
        (a*exp(-((((exp(b)*x))/1000))+c+b))/1000
}

marg.N.resp.function3 <- function(va, co, pd, Cl, P){
        a <-  10000  + 20*Cl
        b <- 2
        c <- (-0.05*pd)
        pr <- co / (va/1000)
        optimalP <- as.data.frame(deriv.model(a,b,c,P)) %>% 
                rename(optimalP = "deriv.model(a, b, c, P)") %>% 
                mutate(diff=abs(optimalP - pr))
        resultP <-cbind(optimalP,P) %>%
                slice(which.min(diff)) %>% 
                select(P)
        newlist <- list(a, b, c, pr, resultP)
        return(newlist)

}

results3 <- as.data.frame(t(mapply(marg.N.resp.function3, 
                                   input.rows3$va, 
                                   input.rows3$co, 
                                   input.rows3$pd,
                                   input.rows3$Cl,
                                   P))) 

results3
```

My understanding is that the last column of the `results3` object should be a single value coming from `resultP`. However, it looks like I am getting the whole `P` vector (last column of output) that I am using as input. I am probably doing something wrong with the (m)apply function for which I am not very familiar.

Any hint will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By passing P as an argument to `mapply` you are iterating over it and recycling your shorter variables.  Two ways around this depending on how you are planing on putting this to use, you could either take P out of both your argument list and the call to `mapply`, or you can create a list that repeats P once for each iteration though.

The first approach, change your function definition by removing "P" from the argument list:

```
library(tidyverse) # for %>%

marg.N.resp.function4 <- function(va, co, pd, Cl){
      a <-  10000  + 20*Cl
      b <- 2
      c <- (-0.05*pd)
      pr <- co / (va/1000)
      optimalP <- as.data.frame(deriv.model(a,b,c,P)) %>% 
            rename(optimalP = "deriv.model(a, b, c, P)") %>% 
            mutate(diff=abs(optimalP - pr))
      resultP <-cbind(optimalP,P) %>%
            slice(which.min(diff)) %>% 
            select(P)
      newlist <- list(a, b, c, pr, resultP)
      return(newlist)

}



results4 <- as.data.frame(t(mapply(marg.N.resp.function4, 
                                   input.rows3$va, 
                                   input.rows3$co, 
                                   input.rows3$pd,
                                   input.rows3$Cl 

                                   ))) 

results4

# V1 V2   V3       V4      V5
# 1 10300  2 -1.9       20       0
# 2 10800  2 -2.5 31.03448       0
# 3 10600  2 -2.5       25       0
# 4 11620  2 -4.3 34.04255       0
# 5 10300  2 -1.9       10 17.4975
```

This approach depends on P being defined outside of the function.  If you are calling with different P vectors you would need to reassign P outside of the function before each run.

The second approach would be more versatile and allow you to use other vectors for P in different runs.

```
results3 <- as.data.frame(t(mapply(marg.N.resp.function3, 
                                   input.rows3$va, 
                                   input.rows3$co, 
                                   input.rows3$pd,
                                   input.rows3$Cl,
                                   list(rep(P, times = 5))

))) 

results3
# V1 V2   V3       V4      V5
# 1 10300  2 -1.9       20       0
# 2 10800  2 -2.5 31.03448       0
# 3 10600  2 -2.5       25       0
# 4 11620  2 -4.3 34.04255       0
# 5 10300  2 -1.9       10 17.4975

identical(results4, results3)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Both solutions worked perfect! Thanks so much. Appreciate your help.